# New Honeywell thermostat doesn't work

Tags: thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I'm a newbie, and I have a question.

My old thermostat is broken, and the fan keeps running and cannot be turned off, but everything else is fine.

So, I replaced it with a new Honeywell RTH8800WF thermostat.

Currently, there are two sets of wires connected to my thermostat.

I believe one set (Rc, G, Y) is from the AC, and the other set (R, W, C) is from the floor heating.

I connected them to my new thermostat, but it doesn't work(blank).

So, I measured the voltage between all the wires.

Rc, G, and Y are around 26VAC, and R, W, and C are also around 26VAC, but Rc and C have almost 60VAC.

I believe the 60VAC is the problem, so I disconnected the AC connection, and the thermostat works

Can you guys please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post photos of before and after wiring.  Also the modal of your old thermostat

Comment: Brand/model of the furnace, as well as clear, focused, well lit pics of the wiring on the stat, the wiring at the furnace and the wiring diagram attached to the furnace will get you a decent answer. As it, you'll get guesses. Once you [edit] your question to include that info, take the [tour] to learn about how things work here and help pass the time until you get some answers or more follow-up questions.

Comment: It sounds like you're potentially trying to use one thermostat to control two different systems? Either way, the RTH8800WF will only work with a standard furnace, 24 VAC. At any rate, you need to *know* what is on the other end of those wires, not guess. The 60 VAC could be a regular 120v electric heating element with a broken neutral.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring please?

Comment: thanks for the reply, problem solved. I changed the c wire from the heating system to the cooling system.